# How make a face-shaped desert storm in a blender?

Tags: effects

I'm studying effects in Blender these days. The effect I want to make this time is a face-shaped desert storm as shown in the picture below, but it didn't go well even if I followed several tutorials.
Could anybody teach me how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question is too broad. Try to focus the question 
into a single specific issue. Break up different questions into 
different posts. You can ask many questions, but it is easier to 
organize things if you deal with one issue at the time. To understand 
how to make better use of this site please take the [tour] and read 
[How do I ask a good question](https://blender.stackexchange.com /help/how-to-ask)
and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: you can make any shape emit smoke, so I guess you could animate a face and make it emit smoke?

Comment: This effect is usually done using two different techniques.  The majority of the storm is done with a physics simulation, in Blender that would be a smoke simulation.  The face is a separate mesh object that has a material related to the storm's material and is animated independently of the storm.  It may or may not also have a smoke simulation or that may be done in compositing.  So you're looking to do some character modeling and animation.

Comment: you can also use particles simulation...but you will need a lot of particles...